# Raspberry Pi cooled with a Peltier cell

Tags: pi-3b+, cooling

I've an RPI3B+ mounted in an IP65 box and placed inside a greenhouse. Obviously the CPU becames really hot during the day and it reaches 80°C (even after the installation of the small heatsinks). I was thinking to use a Peltier cell to cool it down so that I've not to drill holes on the box and moreover, in this way, I can preserve the IP65 being of the enclosure.
Do you think it is a good idea? Does anyone have experience in this scenario?

Thank you

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it's also off-topic. And it's clear you've not done much research. Why not invest some of your time in research to at least rule out some options? For example, if you're inclined to explore Peltier cells, check with a [manufacturer that has some expertise.](https://tetech.com/peltier-thermoelectric-cooler-modules/)

Answer (score 0):

The heat generated by the cell has to be dissipated by placing the heat sink outside the enclosure. It would be necessary to cut an opening in the enclosure to perfectly match the heat sink and seal it with a thermal-rated adhesive such as high temp RTV silicone. Additionally, the cells require airflow provided by a cooling fan. If you require IP65 protection, the external fan becomes a concern.

There are liquid cooling systems for Raspberry Pi boards that provide for radiator placement that may be more convenient than a Peltier cell, but you still have the requirement to puncture the enclosure, and the need for an external fan to cool the radiator. I'd provide links for at least one of them, but every search returns out-of-stock devices. There are quite a few homespun solutions in some videos that may be of value if you are considering such a project.